# use of "carrier" for affected individuals

Tags: medicine

I'm the process of paper drafting and stumbled upon the question, what's the appropriate name for individuals, who are affected by a disease, which is likely due to a mutation.

I was using the term "carriers" until now (like in: group one constists out of mutational carriers, group two is a control group).

Now I've read that the word "carrier" is just short for hereditary carrier (Wikipedia: has inherited a recessive allele for a genetic trait or mutation but does not display that trait)

So how do I refer to patients that are affected by the mutation. I've thought about "patients", but the control group consists out of patients, too.

Is there a correct word for this?

Comment: Perhaps on the English stack? What is the dictionary definition of carrier?

Comment: I'm sorry, the question isn't correct here!

Answer (score 3):

Look at the previous research on this disease, and check what those papers are using to designate these people. If there's a conventional way to refer to them, you'll want to conform to that; if they use different words you'll have some options to choose one you like from.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of the opposite (genetically inherited the mutation with no sign of disease) as an **[asymptomatic carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptomatic_carrier)**, so I checked if *symptomatic carrier* exists. It does not seem to be very common, but it has been used in [medical publications](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24135430).

This does imply a genetic cause though. Which means if you are not yet sure there is a mutation behind it, I would not use the word (genetic) carrier in any case. (Unless you know it is either that or a pathogen, as a patient can also be a symptomatic or asymptomatic carrier of a pathogen.)